# To create a login URI with Django by passing credential details in JSON

Tags: json, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on to create rest api i.e. uri(s) for an application using Django and Django restframework. One of the api end-points is login which will have api end-point like app/login. This uri not only authenticates user with username and password but also checks that if user has a valid session or not.

Additionally, I want to pass this as a JSON in the post request without having any HTML template form, something of the sort :

```
{
    'username' : 'username',
    'password': 'password'
}
```

I know this is dangerous as the 'username' and 'password' will be attached with the POST request as plaintext. But I need so because the front-end part for the application will be designed separately and that will be using just the api end point, so, how can I achieve this ? Also, what is the best way to authenticate the user, session or token ? I have referred many links but not been able to understand the best use case for each authentication type.

Another thing is that I am confused as how does token authentication work? Does that take user credentials or only token which has been given to every user instance and validate the user against that token only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about security, make sure you use SSL on your website. Passwords **will be** sent over the internet as plaintext, so yes, it is very advised you do so. For that you will need an SSL certificate. You can read more about it online.

Even if you had a HTML template form, passwords would still be somewhere in your request, stored as plaintext. From the viewpoint of security it makes no difference.

As for what's the best way to authenticate the user, token or session auth - it depends on your needs. For mobile apps you'd usually use token authentication as it's easier to handle, same goes for single page web applications. But if you're using a framework that has built in session authentication, I'd say that's the best bet.

**Token authentication** takes user credentials in the form of username and password upon login. When the user wants to authenticate requests it sends a header field with token in the form of "Authorization: Token af538baa9045a84c0e889f672baf83ff24". Some people decide to name their headers differently, but it's best if you simply follow convention. Server side (in your case, your Django application) authenticates the user by the token sent in the request's header. It does so by looking up the relationship between the sent token and the user - by means of a table in the database in which it is stored which token belongs to which user.

Comment: thanks for supporting this question and answering the query :) this is what I was looking for !